# Sign Out working locally, but not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

So I'm using devise for login/logout.  I noticed that my sign_out link is working just fine locally, but won't work on Heroku even after I've added, committed and pushed.

Here is what I see in my Heroku logs

```
2014-04-23T22:16:09.987029+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/sign_out host=peaceful-atoll-4795.herokuapp.com request_id=16559a9f-0cff-4179-8aeb-d393ae44de38 fwd="108.233.86.201" dyno=web.1 connect=60ms service=34ms status=404 bytes=1616
```

Note that it tries to use the GET method to sign out when it should be DELETE.  Why is it using the GET method when my routes are correct?

**rake routes:**

```
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
```

**devise.rb setup as such...**

`config.sign_out_via = :delete`

**Link code from my view**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  Logged in as <strong><%= current_user.email %></strong>.
  <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %> |
  <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %> |
  <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks ahead of time for any of your resources or input!

Comment: Please add link code from your view.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel mkay, added it to my question.

Comment: Since `method: :delete` works through query_ujs I suppose there's a JS error on the page. Can you check out the browser dev console?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel ... Yeah, I'm seeing in the console it's missing a js file... `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://peaceful-atoll-4795.herokuapp.com/assets/application-22775dd19bb60dc14c0a7f14a1dd954f.js`

Comment: However, I see in my application.js it should have included jquery_ujs

Comment: So you either have asset compilation problem (see log after git push to Heroku) or there are couple other possibilities. Check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel yeah... I'm actually noticing now that the Console is throwing a few errors because it's looking for assets whose paths are wrong. ie... `jquery_ujs` and a stylesheet.  Thanks for that resource, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as expected my routes were correct, but my app was not able to access `jquery_ujs`.

`jquery_ujs` helps in making `method: :delete` work.

In order to provide the correct path to jquery_ujs I added `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` to my Gemfile and ran `bundle install`

`rails_12factor` also helps in serving static assets in Heroku.

Thanks to @MichaelSzyndel for this helpful resource...

**Rails 4 Asset Pipeline on Heroku:** https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Blind answer here, since I stil can't comment on stackoverflow. :P Would be good to see the applicaiton.js file to make sure.

**Rails >~ 4.0**

You may need to include the rails_12_factor gem into your gemfile. That is because rails 4 won't serve static assets by default, so there could be a problem there. Check it here: https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor#rails-4-serve-static-assets

**Rails >~ 4.1**

You need to declare the precompile of assets into the application.rb or into and assets.rb initializer. This is needed to make the development mode to match the production mode. Sprockets change. Check this: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/84

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me using Rails 5 on Heroku was to simply re-order the js files as follows:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Answer (score 0):

For the quick fix,

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

to

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

in config/devise.rb.
Sadly, it works well in production mode. But it will rise an error in development mode.

here is the original link to the solution. 
[Ruby on Rails: Unable to sign out of application in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195866/ruby-on-rails-unable-to-sign-out-of-application-in-production)